# Jquery ajax function with form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have been trying to solve a simple but, for me, really hard problem.

I have a form and I need to add data from the form to a database, but with form validation. For validation I use the parsley plugin and for some input fields I use select2 plugin.

I try to add form in this way (Comments is in code):

```
  //try to see is zemljiste or vrsta_rada = null to do not add data to database
    var zemljiste = $("#parcele").select2("data");
    var vrsta_rada = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data");

    //Now when I click on #dodaj I need to chech is zemljiste or vrsta_rada == null to do   not start function for adding data but DONT work
    $("#dodaj").click(function () {
        if (zemljiste == null || vrsta_rada == null) {
            alert('PLEASE fill the fields');
        } else {

//HERE if zemljiste and vrsta_rada != null start validation and this also dont work
            $('#myForm').parsley().subscribe('parsley:form:validate', function (formInstance) {
                formInstance.submitEvent.preventDefault(); //stops normal form submit
                if (formInstance.isValid() == true) { // check if form valid or not


                    zemljiste = $("#parcele").select2("data").naziv;
                    id_parcele = $("#parcele").select2("data").id;

                    vrsta_rada = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data").text;
                    //code for ajax event here
    //Here is ajax and when I fill all fields I add data to database but here success and error into ajax dont work???
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "insertAkt.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        async: true,
                        data: {
                            naziv: $("#naziv").val(),
                            parcele: zemljiste,
                            vrsta_rada: vrsta_rada,
                            opis: $("#opis").val(),
                            pocetak: $("#pocetak").val(),
                            zavrsetak: $("#zavrsetak").val(),
                            status: $("#status").val(),
                            id_parcele: id_parcele,
                        }, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
                        dataType: "json",

                        success: function (data) {
//SO if success I add data but this code below dont work also in error dont work
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            drawVisualization();
                            console.log('YESSSSSSS');
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }


                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

With this, I have a few problems...
1. When submit code, the page refreshes and I don't want to do that.
2.When I fill in all the fields, I add data to the database but also add all the previous attempts with incorrect information. Why?
3. Why can I not see what return my success and error into .ajax in console.log ???

Look the pictures:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, my code ADD data to database as many time as I have attemps to add prevous... so if I try to add data 3 times (3 click on ID dodaj) then code add to database 3 times the same data. WHY?

Comment: Because you're requesting that your page submit the data multiple times. Try disabling the submit button onclick.

Comment: Ok, but if data is not valid the script must return user and show alert messages ... the code dont go to the ajax...

Comment: also I have error becouse when zemljiste and vrst_rada == null I dont get alert message ... Why?

Comment: Hi Andrew, try to be more concise with your question. People tend to answer faster to concrete questions. Debug your code and try to figure out what is the problem, then edit your question and post your findings. I know this might be hard when you don't know what is happening but during this exercise probably you will find part of the problem.

Comment: my biggest problem here is that success and error into .ajax dont work. Why?

Comment: you do see what your ERROR is returning...it shows you right where you circled in the picture

Comment: no that is submited data